# Binomial theorem at power series expression

Tags: sequences-and-series, ordinary-differential-equations

Given the binomial theorem of $(1+x)^n$ power series expression as $\sum_{k=0}^n {n\choose k} x^k = (1 + x)^n$.

**Use the binomial theorem and find a power series expression of the from $\sum_{n=0}^\infty {a_n*x^n}$ for $f(x)= \frac{1-(1-4x)^{1/2}}{2x}$.** Please help me with this problem. Thank You

Comment: Can you find the power series for $(1-4x)^{1/2}$, using the binomial theorem? Then it should be easy from there.

Answer (score 1):

$\newcommand{\+}{^{\dagger}}%
 \newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle #1 \right\rangle}%
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace #1 \right\rbrace}%
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack #1 \right\rbrack}%
 \newcommand{\ceil}[1]{\,\left\lceil #1 \right\rceil\,}%
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}%
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}%
 \newcommand{\equalby}[1]{{#1 \atop {= \atop \vphantom{\huge A}}}}%
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,{\rm e}^{#1}\,}%
 \newcommand{\fermi}{\,{\rm f}}%
 \newcommand{\floor}[1]{\,\left\lfloor #1 \right\rfloor\,}%
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}%
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}%
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}%
 \newcommand{\isdiv}{\,\left.\right\vert\,}%
 \newcommand{\ket}[1]{\left\vert #1\right\rangle}%
 \newcommand{\ol}[1]{\overline{#1}}%
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left( #1 \right)}%
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\pp}{{\cal P}}%
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,#2\,}\,}%
 \newcommand{\sech}{\,{\rm sech}}%
 \newcommand{\sgn}{\,{\rm sgn}}%
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{{\rm d}^{#1} #2}{{\rm d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}%
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\, #1 \,\right\vert}$
\begin{align}
\color{#0000ff}{\large\left(1 - 4x\right)^{-1/2}}
&=
\sum_{n = 0}^{\infty}{-1/2 \choose n}\pars{-1}^{n}\pars{4x}^{n}
=
\sum_{n = 0}^{\infty}\pars{-1}^{n}{1/2 + n - 1 \choose n}\pars{-1}^{n}2^{2n}x^{n}
\\[3mm]&=
\sum_{n = 0}^{\infty}{n - 1/2 \choose n}2^{2n}x^{n}
=
\color{#0000ff}{\large%
1 + 4x\sum_{n = 0}^{\infty}{n + 1/2 \choose n + 1}2^{2n}x^{n}}
\end{align}